# AS 3.0 - find the nr of items in an xml that have a specific name before looping thro

Tags: xml, flash

I'm trying to resolve the following:

I'v got a long xml file with a node called 'ows_Sub_x002d_Site' - this has several different values (e.g Home, about us e.t.c) which i then filter to make sure only items with that specific value are then looped thro to build a menu.
That part i got sorted (see below).
The problem i have is that i need to know how many items there are in the xml file with that value before i loop thro the xml and build the menu (so i can determine the overall width of the menu e.t.c).

any clues?

...

function buildTheMenu():void {

var filterBy:String = "Home"; 
var rss:Namespace = new Namespace("#RowsetSchema");
var nrOfItems:Number = xml..rss::row.length();
var iconWidth:Number = 60; // set the size of the icons movie

for each (var row:XML in xml..rss::row)

{

if (row.@ows_Sub_x002d_Site == filterBy){

// here i put the code to build the menu
}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting your menu directly from the XML, you could parse your xml and create an Object or a class to hold the xml data with any properties you may need. Then create your menu using the object properties.

Comment: figured it out. loop thro the xml to create arrays that hold the filtered data. then run a for loop (set to run once the initial filtering loop is completed) to build the menu.

Comment: yep that works! depending on the xml complexity, i like to use custom classes as it allows me to perform operations and generally deal with all the logic issues before handling the view ( in your case a menu ). handy if later on you change your mind on the design!